# I have a loop i can't end on python

Tags: python, xml

I've been doing some Python's code for a course i'm in and i have a problem with a loop i can't end. I don't know where it comes from.

I have tried to put a break on every single "elif" but that's not what i want, because I don't want it to end right after the "else" for example. I wouldn't mind on the other options though.

I have also tried using "return" but maybe there's something i'm doing wrong because I cannot get it to work

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('Paises_XML.xml')
raiz=doc.getroot()
paises=doc.findall("pais")

print("DATOS SOBRE HABITANTES EN CADA PAIS")
print("""
    1- España
    2- Irán
    3- Alemania
    4- EEUU
    5- Libano
    6- Madagascar
    7- Salir
    """)

eleccion=input("Introduzca un número referente a un país de la lista observable: ")

while True:

    if eleccion== "1":
        print("")
        print (paises[0].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[0].find("habitantes").text)

    elif eleccion== "2":
        print("")
        print (paises[1].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[1].find("habitantes").text)

    elif eleccion== "3":
        print("")
        print (paises[2].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[2].find("habitantes").text)

    elif eleccion== "4":
        print("")
        print (paises[3].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[3].find("habitantes").text)

    elif eleccion== "5":
        print("")
        print (paises[4].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[4].find("habitantes").text)

    elif eleccion== "6":
        print("")
        print (paises[5].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[5].find("habitantes").text)


    elif eleccion== "7":
        print("")
        print("¡Hasta pronto!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Opción no válida, elija un número del 1 al 6 para mostrar la información del país correspondiente")
```

I just expect it not to do a loop, everything else is cool I think.
I also wanted to implement an option which could show me every query i'm doing, like gathering them all in one, but I thought that was what was creating the loop so I deleted it.

Comment: Do you want the program to exit only if the user inputs `7` and keep repeating otherwise, or only repeat if they put something other than `1` through `7`? What, in non-technical terms, is your desired behavior here?

Comment: eleccion=input("... ") should inside the while loop

Comment: @Henry. Why did you delete your answer? It was very nice.

Comment: it actually was nice, it made my code much shorter and i could make it work as i expected, publish it again and I will vote it up :)) @HenryWoody

Comment: @victorsionado Thought I was answering the wrong question, but I'll undelete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of eleccion is not changing inside your while loop, please move your input statement after your while statement and retry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to continue the loop as long as the user inputs a valid command. You can do this by moving the `input` line inside the loop and then adding a `break` statement to the `else` condition.

For example:

```py
while True:
    eleccion=input("Introduzca un número referente a un país de la lista observable: ")

    if eleccion == "1":
        # handle
    # ...
    else:
        print("Opción no válida, elija un número del 1 al 6 para mostrar la información del país correspondiente")
        break
```

Also a lot of this code looks like it can be condensed since each case seems to be pretty much the same except for the index used, but that can be derived from the entered command.

For example, we can do:

```py
valid_choices = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

while True:
    eleccion=input("Introduzca un número referente a un país de la lista observable: ")

    if eleccion in valid_choices:
        index = int(eleccion) - 1
        print("")
        print (paises[index].find("nombre").text)
        print (paises[index].find("habitantes").text)
    elif eleccion == "7":
        print("")
        print("¡Hasta pronto!")
        break
    else:
        print("Opción no válida, elija un número del 1 al 6 para mostrar la información del país correspondiente")
        break
```

Comment: This totally made it out! Thank you so much for your time and effort!!

Comment: @victorsionado how come you changed the approved answer?

Answer (score 0):

i see, maybe you can give some variable boolean and make that variable to be threhold  loop for stop that loop e.g:

```
threshold = True 
while threshold: 
    if something:
    threshold = False
```